# what is $K = 2*min(\mu , \mu + \lambda) $ ? is that a matrix or a scalar ? and how does it look? (see image)

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

[image]

I have solved most of this problem. I just don't know what K means so I can't proceed.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/why-image-cannot-be-used-for-explaining-my-maths-problem

Comment: @Schach21: please note that I have already described my question in the title. the image just shows what I am trying to solve but the question is comprehensible even without it. thanks though.